# Text file interpretation

Tags: python

I currently have a text file consisting of scores and names of people who have used a quiz I have created.

> Bob:8
>
> Lucy:5
>
> John:2
>
> Bob:6
>
> Chris:9
>
> Bob:7
>
> Lucy:4
>
> John:3
>
> John:4
>
> Bob:7

In Python, I have became confused as to how you would print out the last three scores for each name in a list. Say, this should print Bob's scores of 7, 7 and 6 beside his name, as well as the last three scores of everyone else (and of course, if they have less than three scores, those will be printed).

I'm currently interpreting the file using a typical method (which probably is not appropriate for my intentions).

```
x = open('Scores.txt', 'r')
```

Comment: You should rather use the `with open` syntax, but yeah, that's the starting point. Now reading the file and using regular expressions to extract the data into a list seems a reasonable solution.

Comment: How would I extract only the last three pieces of data for a name?

Comment: You can do this using a regular expression. The following page contains their syntax in Python and the Python methods that handle them: https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/re.html

Comment: Have you attempted to implement this already? What's your current code?

Comment: @Tonio I'm not sure regex is the best tool for the job - Python has other text parsing tools available.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Well, this was kind of the first thing that came to my mind. What are you referring to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can google (or read just official python docs) on the 4 python things for example - files, strings, dict and list, and end up with a few lines of python code that will handle it. Cause this looks kind of a task to learn some python...

Think the best solution for you if you really wish to learn - just split the task and do it by steps, e.g. you will need to:

1. Read data from file
2. To parse lines (split the name and score)
3. To store it somewhere, e.g. in python dictionary with Name as keys, and a python list as values. e.g.: `scores['Bob'] == [8, 8, 7]` will look understandable and simple.
4. Some thinking magic about empty lines and conditions when to add values to list will give you the result what you want

Sorry, for not providing the my ~10 lines solution, but I think the best way to learn something is to really learn it yourself and be happy of your own achievemnt (even minor) than just copying others code.

Comment: Exactly what I wanted, thanks.

I'm aware that my question came along as kind-of "give me the code!", which was unintended. This answer correctly addresses what I had in mind (which is rather vague), has put me back on track, and given me a plan to work to.

+Best

Answer (score 1):

I'm breaking this up into two parts.

First, here's how to just print the last three scores for each person in the
data set:

```
data = ['Bob:8', 'Lucy:5', 'John:2', 'Bob:6', 'Chris:9', 'Bob:7', 'Lucy:4',
        'John:3', 'John:4', 'Bob:7']
d = {}  # Create an empty dictionary.
for record in data:
    x, y = record.split(':')  # Splits each record on ':'.
    try:
        d[x].append(int(y))  # Append each value to a list in the dict by key, if it already exists...
    except KeyError:
        d[x] = [int(y),]   # ...otherwise, create the list.
for k in d.keys():
    print('%s: ' % k, end='')  # Print the name.
    for v in d[k][-3:]:
        print('%d ' % v, end='')  # Now print the last three values for each person.
    print('')
```

In order to read them in from a file, you simply need to wrap it in a `with` statement:

```
with open('file.txt', 'r') as f:
    d = {}  # Create an empty dictionary.
    for record in f:
        x, y = record.split(':')  # Splits each record on ':'.
        try:
            d[x].append(int(y))  # Append each value to a list in the dict by key, if it already exists...
        except KeyError:
            d[x] = [int(y),]   # ...otherwise, create the list.
    for k in d.keys():
        print('%s: ' % k, end='')  # Print the name.
        for v in d[k][-3:]:
            print('%d ' % v, end='')  # Now print the last three values for each person.
        print('')
```